# UITableView in UIView with swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have been stuck on this problem all day and still have no idea why this problem is so hard to figure out. I have been trying to get a simple UITableview to work. I have managed to get it to appear on the screen (tears of sadness), but I cannot get the table view to update or do anything at all really.

It is important to note that my UITableView is inside of a UIView class that I call in a UIViewController.

Here is my UIView class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class comebackViewController:UIView{
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

 func setup(){

     table = UITableView()

 }

}
```

Here is my main UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewCont: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
var tableViewCont:comebackViewController!
var ListArray:NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ListArray.addObject("hello")
    ListArray.addObject("goodbye")

    print(ListArray.count)

    tableViewCont = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("comebackTableView", owner: self, options: nil).last as! comebackViewController
    tableViewCont.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.height)
    tableViewCont.table = UITableView()
    tableViewCont.setup()
    tableViewCont.table.dataSource = self
    tableViewCont.table.delegate = self
    tableViewCont.table.registerClass(tableViewCellController.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    //Some people say you have to call reloadData like this...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableViewCont.table.reloadData()
        //let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        //self.tableViewCont.table.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    })

    tableViewCont.table.reloadData()

    self.view.addSubview(tableViewCont)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("did get count...\n")
    return self.ListArray.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    print("did get height...\n")
    return 44
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    print("did get number of sections...\n")
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("table did reload...\n")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tableViewCellController

    cell.random1.text = "\(ListArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))"
    cell.random2.text = "me"
    /*
    if let desc = self.items[indexPath.row]["description"] as? NSString   {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = desc
    }*/

    return cell
}

}
```

When I try to run this code the terminal prints out

```
did get number of sections...
did get count...
did get height...
did get height...
did get count...
did get height...
did get height...
```

This means that when I call the reloadData() function is being called, but nothing is ever put into the table. Plus when I call reloadData() I never see "table did reload...\n" printed to the screen. This means there are never any cells being added to the table.

Note: I have gotten this working in objective-c, but swift seems to be a little bit more difficult for me. And I know someone is going to tell me that I have to have a UITableViewController, but the table must be in a separate UIView for my application, thank you!

Comment: Check your tableView's size, it's possible  zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior happens because the tableView's size is zero:

```
tableViewCont = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("comebackTableView", owner: self, options: nil).last as! comebackViewController
tableViewCont.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.height)
tableViewCont.table = UITableView()
tableViewCont.setup() // you instantiate a new UITableView
```

You should set its frame after instantiated:

```
tableViewCont = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("comebackTableView", owner: self, options: nil).last as! comebackViewController
tableViewCont.setup()
tableViewCont.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.height)
```

Comment: This worked great! I probably would have never found that, thanks.